# Ext.Ajax.request is not a function

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I'm having a problem with my `Ext.Ajax.request`. It was working perfectly when I used `prototype.js`, but I was adviced to not use it as it would cause other problems with Ext.

My code looks like this:

```
var me = this;
Ext.Ajax.Request({
    url : 'index.php/ajax/login/', 
    method: 'POST', 
    timeout : 30000,
    params : {
        // Params here
    },
    scope: me,
    success : me.onLoginRequestSuccess,
    failure : me.onLoginRequestFailure
});
```

But it produces this error:

`Ext.Ajax.Request is not a function` 
on
`failure : me.onLoginRequestFailure`

Anyone have any idea what this error means and how I can fix it?

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of cours it's not - it's `request()` http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.Ajax-method-request

Comment: Ah, yes. The old prototype way was to type `new Ajax.Request` - must have been a relic from that. I was trying to fix the failure part of it, but I should have been looking at the call itself. Thanks!